# Flutter FutureBuilder type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to fetch my document from firebase firestore using futurebuilder but there's `this type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'` error I'm facing. The value in firestore is string. I don't know where I am iterating or int is being used. I'd tried adding .toString but no good results.
If anyone know's where I am making mistake then please correct and also I am using this approach to update profile let me know if its fine or I'm doing wrong. P.S its my first firebase based app I am a bit unfamiliar of such errors.

Here's the code

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("userpreferences")
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .get()
                .then((value) {
              return value.data()!["peopletohangoutwith"];
            }),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: DelayedDisplay(
                            delay: const Duration(seconds: 1),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                },
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                      const Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: DelayedDisplay(
                          delay: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          child: Text(
                            "Hang out with",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 26,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: "ProductSans",
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  const DelayedDisplay(
                    delay: Duration(seconds: 2),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          "What type of people you want to hang out with",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontFamily: "ProductSans",
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  DelayedDisplay(
                    delay: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
                      child: TextFormField(
                          initialValue: snapshot.data["peopletohangoutwith"],
                          controller: _peopletohangoutwithController,
                          maxLines: 10,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Write in as detail as possible",
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            filled: true,
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                width: 2.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  DelayedDisplay(
                    delay: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                    child: Center(
                      child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                        label: const Text('Save'),
                        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2A3B6A),
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.save_as_outlined,
                          size: 24.0,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (_peopletohangoutwithController.text.isEmpty) {
                            Get.snackbar(
                              "Error",
                              "Please explain your preference",
                              colorText: Colors.white,
                            );
                          } else {
                            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                .collection("userpreferences")
                                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                .set({
                              "peopletohangoutwith":
                                  _peopletohangoutwithController.text,
                            });
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' error You are facing beacuse you are trying to give string value instead to index you should give index the string value.

```
snapshot.data[index][(string)]
```

Instead of

```
snapshot.data[(string)]
```

Comment: Not helping, didn't worked

Comment: future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("userpreferences")
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .get(); and then try snapshot.data[index][(string)]

Comment: Not working still giving same error :(

Answer (score 0):

This error happens to me if I forgot to check for data existence before using it.
in your builder function but the following checks

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
   return const Text('Something went wrong');
}

if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    return const Text("Loading");
}
```